# Calculated Column Depending on Different Row Value

Tags: 2013, calculated-column, nintex

In our department, we can make offers with different packages. These offers are sometimes only one device and sometimes set. If the proposal (project number) package was submitted in a way, it should be written in the "Main Scope" column. If only one device has been submitted, the name of the device must be entered in the "Main Scope" column.

How do I write this condition?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with a Calculated Column. They can only access data from the same item. You create a SPD 2013 workflow and web service calls to read the other rows.